# How can I verify a field is required using Geb?

Tags: automated-tests, spock, geb

I am writing an automated test using Spock/Geb and I want to verify that a field is actually required.

Here is the code:

[Code for Client Name and Client ID fields which are both required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA2Lz.png)

Here is what I have tried to write that did NOT successfully check to make sure the two fields are actually required:

[Assertions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugdUX.png)

Does anyone have any idea what my code should look like?

Here is what the actual page looks like - I am trying to verify the red asterisk:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTzxZ.png)

Update: The following code worked: 
assert clientConfigPage.modalClientNameTextBox.getAttribute("required")

Comment: Yes, please edit your question, replacing the screenshot links by inline code snippets (indented by 4 spaces so as to get automatic code formatting). Then people can copy & paste in order to reproduce your situation locally. You can also replace the last link by an inline image directly visible in your text. There is an icon uploading an image in the text editor. Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Navigator.hasClass(String className)](http://www.gebish.org/manual/1.0/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html#hasClass(java.lang.String)). This will return a boolean whether the element has a class by the given name. In your example you use .getAttribute("class") == "req" but the class attribute is "required" so you must check for that string literal.

Comment: Thanks for the help Doug!
The following line of code also worked for me:
    assert clientConfigPage.modalClientNameTextBox.getAttribute("required")

Comment: Ahhh I see it's not part of the class but an attribute on its own. Good call. Please reformat your original post so others can use it too